# Stored Procedure Generator tool (CRUD) for oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have a oracle database and would like an easy way to generate stored procedure for crud (Create,Retrieve,Update,Delete). I've been searching around and can't find any obvious tool that will do the job...

Is there any out there that you might be able to suggest?
Would love if it also was modifiable in some way since I have specific names that i want the procedures to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used it, but there's an API generator from ToadWorld: http://www.toadworld.com/Downloads/QuestCodeGenUtilityFreeware/tabid/686/Default.aspx

The above link is **not working** or target is **removed**.